# Summation in a group - SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

My table looks like below. I have to add `spamt` for all three month for a given customer:

```
declare @mytable table
    (
        MNTH CHAR (7),
        BR VARCHAR (4),
        CUSTNO varchar (10),
        SPAMT DECIMAL(10,2)
    )

INSERT INTO @mytable
    SELECT '2016-09', '0001', '4152', 256.25 UNION ALL 
    SELECT '2016-10', '0001', '4152', 856.25 UNION ALL 
    SELECT '2016-11', '0001', '4152', 356.25 UNION ALL 
    SELECT '2016-09', '0001', '5665', 866.25 UNION ALL 
    SELECT '2016-10', '0001', '5665', 656.25 UNION ALL 
    SELECT '2016-11', '0001', '5665', 356.25 

/*
Expected Output
'2016-09','0001','4152',1468.75
'2016-09','0001','5665',1878.75
*/
```

May some one please help me how to get this?

Comment: What is the grouping condition? It seems to be `BR` and `CUSTNO` but then what is the logic for `MNTH`?  The earliest month?

Comment: Please elaborate on the **three month** requirement, is only for a fixed 201609-201611? or do you want something for any given date?

Comment: "for all three month" do you mean for the quarter (year): so sum months 1,2,3 together, 4,5,6 together, 7,8,9 together and then 10,11,12 together? (Better example data would help here: it isn't clear which months are being summed.)

Comment: @DStanley: yes  grouping condition is BR and CUSTNO and earliest month. Thanks

Comment: @Stephen: it is fixed: fixed 201609-201611

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this should do:

```
select min(MNTH), BR, CUSTNO, sum(SPAMT)
from @mytable
where MNTH between '2016-09' and '2016-11'
group by  BR, CUSTNO
```

or to be specific.

```
select min(MNTH), BR, CUSTNO, sum(SPAMT)
from @mytable
where MNTH in ('2016-09', '2016-10', '2016-11')
group by  BR, CUSTNO
```